# How to fill elements of a matrix with indices taken from another matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have the following code, which constructs two matrices `a` (3*2 matrix of zeros) and `b`. I want to replace the `0`s in matrix `a` with `1`s depending on the index location stored in index `b`. I want to do it without a `for` loop.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((3, 2))
b = np.array([0, 1, 0])
```

The output should be

```
c = [[1, 0],
     [0, 1],
     [1, 0]]
```

Comment: Can you show `c` as a proper 2D array?

Comment: So are you saying that each element of `b` corresponds to a row of `a`, and tells you which index to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy fancy indexing is your friend here. To make `b` work as the column index, you need an array of equal size to `b` which will tell you the row that each index applies to:

```
a[np.arange(b.size), b] = 1
```

This modifies `a` in-place. If that is not what you want, make a copy first:

```
c = a.copy()
c[np.arange(b.size), b] = 1
```

Comment: You can also use `a[range(len(b)),b] = 1`. Perhaps you can add this as an alternative

Comment: @Bazingaa. If I'm not mistaken, that is a false memory saving device. Internally, the index will be expanded to a numpy array regardless of how you pass it in.

Comment: Anyway since NumPy is already used to create the matrix, it rules out the point of import overkill. So yeah, `np.arange` makes sense

Comment: @Bazingaa. Exactly. If you're using the library already, theres no point in holding back.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you so much this works perfect for me

Comment: @AzizUrRehman. I'm glad it worked out for you. Please select the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. That will remove your question from the unanswered queue, and give us both some points.